# `could not find function "get<-"` when trying to add new column

Tags: r

I want to add a new column to a dataframe I made with `assign()`.

```
varname <- "vehicles"

assign(
  x = varname,
  value = cars
)

get(varname)

get(varname)$AnotherCol <- "Test"
```

But when I run this code, I get this error.

```
Error in get(varname)$AnotherCol <- "Test" : 
  could not find function "get<-"
```

How do I add a column to a variable I made with `assign()`?

Comment: Instead of using `assign`, try with `[[`  `cars[[varname]] <- "Test"`

Comment: @akrun I need to use `assign()` to make the variable `vehicles`. I want to add a column named `AnotherCol`.

Comment: You meant to create an object `vehicles`?  What is `cars`?

Comment: @akrun Correct.

Comment: I would assume `cars` to be some `vector`?

Comment: `cars` is a dataframe that comes with R in many base installations.

Comment: @akrun I want to use `assign()` to assign `cars` to `vehicles`. Then I want to access `vehicles` via `get("vehicles")`, and add the new column.

Comment: Don't do it with `get`, you already know the name of the df, `vehicles$AnotherCol <- "Test"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I’m using a minimal example. I’m setting variable names via loop, so I use assign() to make the objects.

Comment: What folks are pushing you towards here is the general principle that using assign/get is almost always unnecessary and in fact often actively harmful because they tend to lead you into difficult situations like this. Typically the best solution is to back up and use a better approach without assign/get at all.

Comment: @joran In my non-example code, I'm trying to make a bunch of objects in a loop. What's the best way to do this, if not using `assign()` to name them?

Comment: As alluded to above I think, you should always prefer a single named list over a collection of individually defined objects.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please provide the code and data of what you're really trying to do that you think requires the use of `get` and `assign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we really need to create a new column based on the string object `varname`, then call `assign` a second time and assign (`[[<-`) the new column "AnotherCol" with the `value` "Test"

```
assign(varname, `[[<-`(get(varname), "AnotherCol", value = "Test"))
head(get(varname))
#  speed dist AnotherCol
#1     4    2       Test
#2     4   10       Test
#3     7    4       Test
#4     7   22       Test
#5     8   16       Test
#6     9   10       Test
```

NOTE: This is not the recommended way though.  It could be done without using `assign` or `get`.  Assuming that the assignment comes from a loop, it may be better to create a single `list` instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment

For e.g. the 'AnotherCol' with the value 'Test' can be created in a `list` of datasets with either `base R` methods

```
lapply(list(cars, mtcars), transform, AnotherCol = "Test")
```

Or using `tidyverse` methods

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(cars, mtcars) %>%
       map(mutate, AnotherCol = "Test")
```

Comment: Thanks. I've read everyone's comments and have decided against using `assign()` and `get()`. Instead I will add the newly-made objects to a `list()`.

Comment: @Username  Let's say you have two datasets and want to create the 'AnotherCol' in both `library(tidyverse);lst(cars, mtcars) %>% map(mutate, AnotherCol = "Test")`